# Отслеживание состояния буфера обмена при отмене и повторе действия

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при появлении данных в буфере для отката, активировалась кнопка отмены. Когда в буфере больше нет данных, которые можно откатить, но есть для повтора - активировалась кнопка повтора и дезактивировалась кнопка отмены. Соответственно, когда есть данные для отката и повтора работали 2 кнопки.
Не смог найти информацию по конкретному вопросу, поэтому сделал по своему.
Когда ввожу символы в RichtextBox - активируется кнопка отмены.

```
    private void RichTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Clipboard.ContainsText() == true)
        {
            cancel.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Когда нажимаю кнопку отмены - активируется повтор

```
    private void cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //отмена последнего события
    {
        RichTextBox.Undo();
        if (Clipboard.ContainsText() == true)
        {
            repeat.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            repeat.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void repeat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //повтор последнего события
    {
        RichTextBox.Redo();
        if (Clipboard.ContainsText() == false)
        {
            cancel.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Несмотря на неочень правильный подход, все работает, но при тех моментах, когда откатывать больше нечего - кнопки остаются активны.
Что посоветуйте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте для проверки состояния буфера свойства `CanUndo` и `CanRedo`

В MSDN в описаниях [RichTextBox.CanRedo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.canredo(v=vs.110).aspx) и [TextBoxBase.CanUndo()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.canundo(v=vs.110).aspx), в примерах кода, показано использование данных свойств.